# May I get ng-model's key instead of value in ng-value?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set up a radio selector based on an array and return the key instead of the value to the server.

Here is the array:

```
$scope.customer_types = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'other'];
```

Here is the radio selector:

```
<label style="margin-right:15px"><input type="radio" ng-model="ctype" ng-value="customer_type" name="customer_type">{{customer_type}}</label>
```

Now $scope.ctype will store the selected customer type and return a number, for example if I select `other` it should send out `4` to the server. I can do a reverse filter for this but it seems to me if I can use something like `ng-value="customer_type[key]"` it would be a lot easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat="(customer_key,customer_type) in customer_types"`

You will need to separate key and value in `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the key to be the position of the element in the array, you could use `$index` to fetch the selected customer type.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.customer_types = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'other'];
  $scope.selectedType = function(index) {
    $scope.ctype = index;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="customer_type in customer_types">
    <label style="margin-right:15px">
    <input type="radio" ng-value="$index" name="customer_type" ng-model="ctype" ng-click="selectedType($index)">{{customer_type}}</label>
  </div>

  Selected Customer type : {{ctype}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ng-repeat="(key,customer_type) in customer_types" and change radio button as :

```
<label style="margin-right:15px"><input type="radio" ng-model="ctype" ng-value="key" name="customer_type">{{customer_type}}</label>
```